# Save values of searchtree in array, without using global variables

Tags: ruby, recursion, global-variables, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to save the values from a searchtree in an array, but i can't do it without a global variable. I would like to keep the recursion if possible.

```
$array = []
def to_array(s)
  if s != {}
  $array << s[:value]
  to_array(s[:left])
  to_array(s[:right])
  end
end
```

A searchtree looks like this:

```
st1 = {:key=>2, :value=>0,
   :left=>{},
   :right=>{:key=>17, :value=>1,
            :left=>{:key=>13, :value=>2,
                    :left=>{:key=>10, :value=>4,
                            :left=>{},
                            :right=>{:key=>11, :value=>5,
                                     :left=>{},
                                     :right=>{}}},
                    :right=>{:key=>14, :value=>6,
                             :left=>{},
                             :right=>{}}},
            :right=>{:key=>22, :value=>3,
                     :left=>{},
                     :right=>{:key=>48, :value=>7,
                              :left=>{:key=>42, :value=>8,
                                      :left=>{},
                                      :right=>{}},
                              :right=>{:key=>77, :value=>9,
                                      :left=>{},
                                      :right=>{}}}}}}
```

How would i go about saving the values in an array without using a global variable ?

Thanks in advance for all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass the variable to the method and return it:

```
def to_array(tree, array = [])
  unless tree.empty?
    array << s[:value]
    to_array(s[:left], array)
    to_array(s[:right], array)
  end

  array
end
```

You can call the method in the first recursion without creating an array first because `array` has an empty array as a default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer suggested, default parameters are a good way to avoid global variables. You can also use an instance variable:

```
@array = []
def to_array(s)
  if s != {}
    @array << s[:value]
    to_array(s[:left])
    to_array(s[:right])
  end
  @array
end
```

If you don't define a class, that will be an variable under the `main` object. Alternatively, you can return a local variable:

```
def to_array(s)
  array = []
  if s != {}
    array << s[:value] 
    array << to_array(s[:left]) if s[:left] != {}
    array << to_array(s[:right]) if s[:right] != {}
  end
  array.flatten
end
```

(This could probably be tightened up a bit to avoid doing so many checks for an empty hash.)